# Equation of A line in an Isosceles Triangle

Tags: triangles, slope

In an isosceles triangle ABC,the coordinates of the point B and C on the base BC are respectively (1,2) and (2,1).If the equation of the line AB is y=2x, then find the equation of the line AC.

I have tried finding slopes of AB and and BC.Then I found the tangent of Angle between them. As base angles in an isosceles triangle are equal,I equated it with the tangent of the angle ACB.Then I found the slope of AC, but I am getting the wrong answer even after trying 6 times.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WLOG. $A(t,2t)$

Now use $|AB|=|AC|$

Comment: Thanks,can you please tell me what I did wrong in My approach.

Comment: @user150093, the absolute values of the angles will need same, the signs will be opposite

Comment: Means the sign of tangent will reverse?

Comment: @user150093, By reverse, I mean $m_{AB}=-m_{AC}$$